# WebSphere - Horizontal Scalability

Tags: websphere

Does WebSphere 6.1 (not the ND edition) support the creation of a server group/cluster with multiple nodes possibility spanning across multiple machines. The idea is to create a horizontal cluster for load-balancing and fail-over support. Some previous versions of WAS supported this out-of-the-box through an advanced admin. console but what about this version.

The Base Edition of WAS allows the creation of multiple WAS instances but what about the creation of clusters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to tell you that bud, but as far as i know - only ND allows you to do clustering from the WAS perspective. If you want a failover, just create dmgr profile and add node. That should not be a problem since in 6 and above you don't need any additional software - it's just another profile. But if you don'w want to do this, you may think about doing a failover on the different level, for example on F5 or something like that. It's not the sam, but in some cases might work.

Comment: You can use edge level load balancing/fail over with the IBM Load Balancer and the IBM HTTP Server-Plugin. However more sophisticated clustering (session failover, etc.) is only available in ND.